# correct order of elements in tuple of QtCore.QAbstractListModel data list item

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, pyside6

I am adding rows to QListView vidget.

```
self.model.todos.append((Status, "row_text"))
```

QListView is connected to data model (TodoModel), which contains totos[] list of tuples.
This tuple contains a text string and a picture.

I see that correct order of elements in the tuple depends on the order of extraction in data method in TodoModel (compare Variant A and B)

```
def data(self, index, role):
    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
        _, text = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant A
        # text, _ = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant B
        return text

    if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole:
        status, _ = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant A
        # _, status = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant B
        if status:
            return QtGui.QImage('tick.png')
```

So, the correct order when adding will be different:

```
self.model.todos.append((True, "row1_text"))  # correct order for A
self.model.todos.append(("row2_text", True))  # correct order for B
```

Seems that QListView when getting data for a text uses getData with role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole and when looking for a picture - with a role=Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole
**Could someone elaborate on this behaviour?**

Full code for example:

```
import sys
from PySide6 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from MainWindow import Ui_MainWindow


class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, todos=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.todos = todos or []

    def data(self, index, role):
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            _, text = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant A
            # text, _ = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant B
            return text

        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole:
            status, _ = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant A
            # _, status = self.todos[index.row()]  # Variant B
            if status:
                return QtGui.QImage('tick.png')

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = TodoModel()
        self.todoView.setModel(self.model)

        self.model.todos.append((True, "row1_text"))  # correct order for A
        self.model.todos.append(("row2_text", False))  # correct order for B

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: what is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi Alexander
I just whant to understand if my assumption is correct and QListView sends getData  DisplayRole argument when filling a row with a text and when looking for a picture - a DecorationRole argument

Comment: Your question is unclear, especially the part where you say that you need to invert the order of insertion. Why would you do that? Even with your code, it doesn't make any sense if you try it: in fact the first item will be "row1_text" and the second "false". I suggest you to read the documentation about the [Qt model view programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/model-view-programming.html).

Comment: The role is just a key for looking up the different value types required to render a row. So `data()` will be called multiple times per row to get all the required values. The underlying structure is roughly equivalent to a list of dict, where the list indexes are row numbers, the dict-keys are [item data roles](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum) and the dict values are data items. Your `data()` implementation just needs to know which tuple index maps to which role. There is no "correct" or "best" ordering - it's entirely up to you to decide which one makes most sense.

Comment: @Leo As you can see from the code, when `data()` is called it is called with one index and one role.  That role could be the Display Role, the Decoration Role, or some other role as well.  Whatever is returned from that call assuming it's the right type, is what is rendered to the view.  The method will be called multiple times for each row displayed by the view.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve, but the ordering of your tuples only has as much to do with the data-role as you want it to.

For example if you had two images for your Todo App, one with an empty box (`empty.png`), and the other that had the same box but with a green check,(`dont.png`) you could construct your model like this:

```
class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, todos=None):
        self.empty_img = QtGui.QImage("empty.png")
        self.done_img = QtGui.QImage("done.png")
        super().__init__()
        self.todos = [
            (True, "Call John at 2pm"),
            (False, "Pick up Wendy at 6pm")
        ]

    def data(self, index, role):
        item = self.todos[index.row()]
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return item[1]
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole:
            if item[0] is True:
                return self.done_img
            else:
                return self.empty_img

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)
```

You could do the exact same thing using the reverse ordering too. This is one of the benefits of using the Abstract Models, they are extremely flexible and you can essentially store your data in whatever way you would like.

```
class TodoModel(QtCore.QAbstractListModel):
    def __init__(self, todos=None):
        self.empty_img = QtGui.QImage("empty.png")
        self.done_img = QtGui.QImage("done.png")
        super().__init__()
        self.todos = [
            ("Call John at 2pm", True),
            ("Pick up Wendy at 6pm", False)
        ]

    # Since the ordering has changed so must the indexes below
    def data(self, index, role):
        item = self.todos[index.row()]
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DisplayRole:
            return item[0]
        if role == Qt.ItemDataRole.DecorationRole:
            return self.done_img if item[1] else self.empty_img
         

    def rowCount(self, index):
        return len(self.todos)
```

Hopefully that answers your question.